# BPF map find the number of elements

Tags: c, ebpf, bcc-bpf

How do you find the number of elements in a [BPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) map? I can't find any useful information in the bcc reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

#### Low-level

Once you have a file descriptor on your map (retrieved from a pinned path or from the map id for example), you can call the `bpf()` system call with its `BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD` subcommand. This will fill the `attr` argument with a pointer to a `struct bpf_map_info`, defined [in the user API header file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L5410). In particular, `attr->max_entries` will be set to the maximum number of entries for the map. Wrappers such as `bpf_obj_get_info_by_fd()` from libbpf can help with the syscall details.

Array maps have a fixed number of entries, but some types such as hash maps have a maximum number, and an actual number of entries set at a current time. There is no counter available for the current number of entries in such case, the solution consists in iterating over all the entries to count them.

#### In BCC

For BCC, using the Python wrappers, I think (but have not tested) that you can access the maximum number of entries for a map `foo` with `foo.max_entries` (the attribute is defined in [the definition](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/v0.21.0/src/python/bcc/table.py#L1279) of the base class `TableBase`). I also believe that you can use the operator `len` to get the current number of elements for some map types, for example [for hash tables](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/v0.21.0/src/python/bcc/table.py#L797): `len(foo)`. But again, I have not tried.